# Does beer really help to improve muscles?

Tags: health

I have heard from many people that beer helps to improve muscles.  Generally one way to improve muscle is by exercise (maybe dance, gym, games).  As far as I know, beer (alcohol) is a diuretic, which makes kidney produce more urine, so drinking beer too much can lead to dehydration.  So the combination of beer and exercise (sweating) would lead to a worse condition.

So my question's are:

- Does it really help to improve muscle?
- If it does, then how?  And when should it can be taken?  Before or after exercise?

Comment: It improves only the beer muscle.

Comment: This is off topic. While it uses beer in the question, it would be better suited in physical fitness or nutrition stack exchanges. Unfortunately I cannot vote to close because the only redirect is to homebrewing.

Comment: @Grohlier use "this question does not appear to be about beer" don't let lack of options stop you from casting the vote.

Comment: While this question would probably be on-topic for a health/fitness site, it is probably also on-topic here.  Do we actually gain anything by trying to close it?

Comment: @JamesHenstridge tbh the whole line of "does beer really do X" doesn't seem like something an expert would be interested in.

Comment: It does sound like something that someone interested in beer might be interested in though.  Isn't that the sort of person this site is targeted at?

Comment: In theory, the private beta is for filling the site up with a small number of expert-level questions. Then, when the public beta starts, experts who weren't involved at first see this great new place, and start to join up. The presence of experts then attracts interested non-experts. Since we're at the very beginning of the public beta, this could go either way. I'm not trying to make a decision for you, just provide some background so you and other community members can work it out. Perhaps bring it up on [the meta site](http://meta.beer.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was a study at the University of Tokushima that showed beer containing flavaprenin 
(8-Prenylnaringenin), which is found in hops, limited muscle atrophy in debilitated lab mice. The idea that humans could have benefits of flavaprenin through drinking beer is not quite right, as you would die from alcohol poisoning before you would see the benefits.

if you are interested here is a non-technical article on the topic: http://www.dailymail.co.uk/health/article-2208966/Beer-help-strong-old-age--youd-need-drink-83-litres-A-DAY.html

Comment: Welcome, @CryptcWriter! Thanks for your contribution.